# Put, insert, or set the text of a text% object in Racket

Tags: user-interface, racket

I have a [`text%`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/text_.html?q=text%25) object. I can get stuff out of it with [`get-text`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/text_.html?q=get-text#%28meth._%28%28%28lib._mred%2Fmain..rkt%29._text~25%29._get-text%29%29), but there doesn't seem to be to actually put text into the `text%` object.

Is there a constructor field for setting the text, like setting the labels of other GUI elements. Alternatively, I would expect something like a `set-text` method for setting the text.

So, how do I set the text of a `text%` object? Or is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `set-text` method and you can't set the text in the constructor.

However, the [`insert`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/editor___.html?q=insert#%28meth._%28%28%28lib._mred%2Fmain..rkt%29._editor~3c~25~3e%29._insert%29%29) method does what you want.

```
#lang racket/gui

(define t (new text%))
(send t insert "hello world")
```

You can check to make sure this worked with `get-text`:

```
> (send t get-text)
"hello world"
```